# Weird issue with URLSearchParams() in Angular2

Tags: url, angular

I have a weird issue that appears with `URLSearchParams()` it works only when defining `var search` (i.e if I change the variable name to `var otherName`) it does not work!!

However, for some reason it works only when the name is `search` !! which is totally not logical at all.

Any idea on what's happening here?

```
  constructor(http) {
  this.http = http;
  this.genre = null;
  this.dishes = null;

  //this one works fine
  var search = new URLSearchParams();
  search.set('order', '-ordersNo');

  //Here is the issue (to make it work, I need to remove the previous search declaration, and rename the below var limit to search)
  var limit = new URLSearchParams();
  limit.set('limit', '2');

  this.http.get('https://example.com/classes/Mn', { limit }).subscribe(data => {
  this.dishes = data.json().results;
  });


  this.http.get('https://example.com/classes/Genre',{ search }).subscribe(data => {
  this.genre = data.json().results;
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you actually want to have it like this:

```
{ search: search }

//and 

{ search: limit }
```

`options` parameter of http get method must have the following signature:

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string;
    method?: string | RequestMethod;
    search?: string | URLSearchParams;
    headers?: Headers;
    body?: string;
}
```

but `{limit }` actually is the same as `{ limit: limit }`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What you suggest works, but I still don't understand why when I change search to another name it stops working! really weird!!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's a shortcut of JavaScript : `{ search }` is equivalent to `{ search: search }` and `{ limit }` to `{ limit: limit }`.

It works fine for the first case since Angular2 expects a `search` property to define query parameters. If you want to use the `limit` variable, you can't use this shortcut and you need to use the following: `{ search: limit }`.

Comment: { search: limit } certainly works! But, let's see the other scenario which is removing the 'var search' leaving only 'var limit' when calling limit after, it does not work! Is search a reserved or what?

Comment: The structure of the object to pass to Angular2 is described in the `RequestOptionsArgs` interface as @kemsky stated... `limit` isn't a supported property by Angular2...